# Updatable Grid using angularjs and php (backend)

Tags: php, angularjs

I have to create an updatable grid like this.

[image]

Users will edit this grid and updated information will be saved to db asynchronously. Since multiple users works on same grid, when other user update a particular column , change shall be reflected to all users.

I am new to angularjs. How shall i implement this functionality using angularjs with backend in php.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24206272/1654026

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be bigger than just updating a grid with AngularJS, so there are some points to consider:

#### communication of multiple users

You may want to use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets) to provide real-time communication across multiple clients. On the php side you could use something like [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) to provide WebSockets and on the client side you interact with them using [angular-websocket](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-websocket). The client part would look like

```
WebSocket.onmessage(function(event) {
  // update the state
});
```

If that's too much you can always poll the state of your grid from the server using ajax and provide a pseudo-realtime communication. This could look like

```
$interval($http.get('your url').success(function(result) {
  // update the state
}), 30 * 1000) // polls every 30 seconds
```

However, I'd really recommend digging into WebSockets - they are what you want.

#### the grid itself

Once you have your state updated using either WebSockets or ajax polls, you could have a fully flexible 2d grid as follows:

```
// the controller
.controller('GridCtrl', function($scope, WebSocket) {
  WebSocket.onmessage(function(event) {
    $scope.grid = event.data;
  });
  $scope.updateGrid = function() {
    WebSocket.send($scope.grid);
  });
})
```

```
<!-- the template -->
<form ng-submit="updateGrid()">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="row in grid">
    <div class="col" ng-repeat="col in row">
      <input ng-model="col">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```